# "printf( "Line read: %s\n", input );" wont print out the full input string. C programming

Tags: c

Program should be printing this:

```
$ this is a test
Line read: this is a test
Token(s): 
 this
 is
 a
 test
4 token(s) read
```

But it's cutting off the Line read: to this:

```
$ this is a test
Line read: this
Token(s): 
 this
 is
 a
 test
4 token(s) read
```

It only takes the first word of the input...

code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char input[ 256 ];
    char *token;

    while ( 1 )
    {   
        printf("$ ");

        fgets( input, 256, stdin );
        int count = 0;      
        token = strtok( input, " \n" );
        if ( count == 0 && strcmp( input, "exit" ) == 0 )
        {
            exit( 0 );
        }

        printf( "Line read: %s\n", input );
        printf( "Token(s): \n" );

        while( token != NULL )
        {
            count++;
            printf( " %s\n", token );
            token = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
        }   

        printf( "%d token(s) read\n\n", count );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you use `strtok()`, it mangles the string it is working on, putting nulls at places it considers convenient.  You can't print the whole string after using `strtok()` on it (unless `strtok()` failed to find any of your delimiter characters).

Comment: note that count will allways be 0 in the if statement

Comment: Note that you should also tokenize on tab characters: `strtok(input, " \t\n");` although it makes a very basic scanner that does not recognize strings or command separators.

Answer (score 4):

`strtok()` modifies the input string, putting a null byte at the end of each token. So when you do:

```
token = strtok(input, " \n");
```

it puts a null byte after the first word in `input`. When you print `input`, that null byte terminates the string.

Move the line that prints `input` to before the first call to `strtok()`. Or make a copy of `input` and operate on that with `strtok()`.

Comment: If I put the print statement before the strtok() then when I type "exit" to close out the program it prints "Line read: exit" before it exits out. And I cant have it do that.

Comment: Then make a copy of the input and print that.

Answer (score 0):

Using an inputTEMP to copy the value of input, I got the program to work.
Thank you to @Barmar.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char input[ 256 ];
    char inputTEMP [ 256 ];
    char *token;

    while ( 1 )
    {   
        printf("$ ");

        fgets( input, 256, stdin );
        strcpy(inputTEMP, input);
        int count = 0;

        token = strtok( input, " \n" );

        if ( count == 0 && strcmp( input, "exit" ) == 0 )
        {
            exit( 0 );
        }
        if ( strcmp ( input, "exit") != 0)
        {
            printf( "Line read: %s", inputTEMP );               
        }


        printf( "Token(s): \n" );

        while( token != NULL )
        {
            count++;
            printf( " %s\n", token );
            token = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
        }   

        printf( "%d token(s) read\n\n", count );
    }
    return 0;
}
```